# Vim: Make cursor move up/down but stay in the same line

Tags: vim

Is there a way to make the vim cursor move in lines vertically? Here's an example:

[image]

So the cursor is at the word `nisi`, and I want to move to `Pellentesque`. I came from `Sublime`, so my instinct is to press down (in this case `j`) but it jumps to `line 2`. Is there way to configure that by pressing `j` I move down but got to `Pellentesque` and not `line 2`? I can only move to it the normal way by moving horizontally (`l`,`w`,`e` etc...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gj` is the command. You can remap `j` to `gj` to have its behavior by default.

here is some of the mapppings that I use and find useful(including the answer one), and they are simple, not depend on any functions or packages

```
map j gj
map k gk
map Y y$ # Yank to the end of line
nnoremap L Lzz<CR> # go to bottom of screen and center on that line
nnoremap H Hzz<CR> # go to top of screen and center on that line
inoremap jk <esc> # just type jk to exit inserting mode
inoremap <esc> <nop> # don`t do anything in insert mode
vnoremap v <Esc> #  Quit visual mode
nnoremap U <C-r> # Redo
nnoremap n nzz # search and center
nnoremap N Nzz # search and center
nnoremap * *zz # search and center
nnoremap # #zz # search and center
nnoremap g* g*zz # search and center
```

Answer (score 1):

VIM makes a distinction between 'real lines' and 'display lines'.

By default the `j` and `k` commands move up and down 'real lines'.

The line numbers in your screenshot demonstrate that VIM count's 3 'real lines'.

To switch to using 'display lines' instead, which will enable you to move up and down each individual line you can remap the `j` and `k` keys to `gj` and `gk` which is the default way of moving up and down 'display lines'.

```
nnoremap k gk
nnoremap gk k
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap gj j
```